# Call another view from button in popoverview

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a searchcontrollerviewcontroller, detailviewcontroller and a filterviewcontroller

In Appdelegate I added the first 2 as splitview controller and delegate to detailviewcontroller like this:

```
self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController, detailNavigationController, nil];
```

when the ipad turns it shows buttons for the popoverview

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{  

    UIBarButtonItem *filterbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Filter"     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(showFilterPopover:)];

    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Search", @"Search results");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButtonItem,filterbutton, nil] animated:YES];

    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}
```

I init the filterview in here

```
-(void)showFilterPopover: (id) sender{

    FilterViewController *controller = [[FilterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FilterViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIPopoverController *popover =
    [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];

    popover.delegate = self;
    self.masterPopoverController = popover;


    [self.masterPopoverController
         presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
}
```

But nothing happens, the popover works for the detailview but not for the filterview....
Am I forgetting something ?

Comment: self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController, detailNavigationController, nil]; here u r not setting the delegate to filterviewcontroller and moreover u r not adding the filterviewcontroller in the array .. i suppose if you do this it will work

Comment: @Sydney the delegate is detailviewController not filter view... a splitviewcontroller has only 2 views ?